How can I remove rusted bathtub overflow plate screws?
We tried to extract the rusted screws from the PVC behind the tub overflow plate. We tried the Speed away  grip pro extractor set to no avail. We tried drilling through the stubs to no avail. We tried filing the stubs to make a more level surface to drill through to no avail.


Do you have easy access to replace the overflow?

Those shouldn't be that hard to remove from plastic. Even a good pliers should do. An extractor should be effortless. Why don't we see shiny metal where your efforts were made?

Cut a slot in screw head with a rotary tool cutoff blade for a screwdriver blade. That said, as @isherwood states, it looks completely unmarked!
